# batch code to give paths to files in folders and subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I want to get the list of all files in 1 folder (including subfolders). So let's say I have folder A, Subfolers A1,A2 and files B.txt,C.csv,D.json

```
C:\A\B.txt
C:\A\A1\C.csv
C:\A\A1\D.json
```

This is just a simple example. The stuff I am using has multiple folders and files in it. So for each file that there is I want output to be

```
C:\A\B.txt
C:\A\A1\C.csv
C:\A\A1\D.json
```

in some file named paths.txt

How can this be done?

Comment: All you want is a list of all the files in one folder (and its subfolders) stored in a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dir /b /s /a:-d *.txt *.csv *.json>paths.txt
```

Comment: This code gave me all the files in folders sub folders (with those extensions). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /F %%A in ('dir /b /s /a-d "C:\A\A1"') do echo %%~dpnxA>>paths.txt
```

This will grab all files in C:\A\A1 and its subdirectories without including the subdirectories themselves in that list.